# Improving this mix in

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mixins

I’m trying to improve this mixin and the one thing that’s bothering me is I can’t seem got get the rest of the module to know about the base property in the self.included(base) so I’m having to pass base to every module method.  Is there a better way of doing this:

```
module SearchSort
      def self.included(base)
        # binds included class's class methods
        base.send :extend, ClassMethods
        initialize_scopes(base)
      end

      def self.initialize_scopes(base)
        initialize_type_scope(base)
        initialize_product_name_scope(base)
      end

      def self.initialize_type_scope(base)
        base.scope :for_work_type, lambda { |work_type|
        Rails.logger.debug("-----(45) work_type #{work_type}")
        terms = process_terms(work_type)
      base.where(
        terms.map { '(LOWER(workable_type) LIKE ?)' }.join(' AND '),
        *terms.map { |e| [e] * 1 }.flatten)
    }
  end

  def self.initialize_product_name_scope(base)
    base.scope :for_product_name, lambda { |product_name|
      terms = process_terms(product_name)
      base.where(
        terms.map { '(LOWER(products.name) LIKE ?)' }.join(' AND '),
        *terms.map { |e| [e] * 1 }.flatten
      ).joins(:product)
    }
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def pid_opts
      [%w(Newly\ Added newly_added), %w(Waiting waiting),
       %w(Ready ready), %w(Working working),
       %w(Error error), %w('Error Retry', 'error_retry'),
       %w(Done done), %w(Gated gated)
      ]
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: One alternative would be to add class-level variable to hold `base` during the initialization phase and then remove it. Personally I'd prefer passing the argument instead, like you already do.

Answer (score 0):

instead having the auto-registering-magic in `included` method, i'd just add an initializaton-method to the module like `initialize_scopes` and call in from where classes are extended using that module

```
extend SearchSort
initialize_scopes
```

since extend is used, methods defined in the module are executed in the class context (it's all about the context of `self`).

to give you an example, i use this pattern for something like `acts_as_api`:

```
module ApiHandling
  def expose_api(*fields)
    acts_as_api

    api_accessible :ios_v1 do |template|
      fields.each { |field| template.add field }
    end
  end
end
```

used like this:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend ApiHandling
  expose_api :id, :name, :description, ...
```